# Generate a new value for all values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array looks like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["FI_ID"]=>
    string(3) "577"
    ["FI_Stru_Code"]=>
    string(13) "MCTS-70-631/1"
    ["FI_Ins_NO"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["FI_Type"]=>
    string(10) "Percentage"
    ["FI_Ins_Amount"]=>
    string(5) "60.00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["FI_ID"]=>
    string(3) "578"
    ["FI_Stru_Code"]=>
    string(13) "MCTS-70-631/1"
    ["FI_Ins_NO"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["FI_Type"]=>
    string(10) "Percentage"
    ["FI_Ins_Amount"]=>
    string(5) "40.00"
  }
}
```

I want to make it like this

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["FI_ID"]=>
    string(3) "577"
    ["FI_Stru_Code"]=>
    string(13) "MCTS-70-631/1"
    ["FI_Ins_NO"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["FI_Type"]=>
    string(10) "Percentage"
    ["FI_Ins_Amount"]=>
    string(5) "18000.00" // 30000*60% (I want to apply this to every FI_Ins_Amount)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["FI_ID"]=>
    string(3) "578"
    ["FI_Stru_Code"]=>
    string(13) "MCTS-70-631/1"
    ["FI_Ins_NO"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["FI_Type"]=>
    string(10) "Percentage"
    ["FI_Ins_Amount"]=>
    string(5) "12300.00"  // 30000*40%
  }
}
```

I tried using the following function

```
$courseFee = 30000;

function installmentFixed($value,$courseFee)
{
    return $value["FI_Ins_Amount"]/100  * $courseFee;
}

$installmentFixed = array_map("installmentFixed", $installment);

var_dump($installmentFixed);
```

But it doesn't seems to work correctly. Why ?

It returns

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  float(0)
  [1]=>
  float(0)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work correctly? Are there any error messages? What was returned?

Comment: added the retrun values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i want

```
$courseFee = 30000;

$installmentFixed = array_map(function($value) use ($courseFee)
{
   return array("FI_Ins_NO" => $value["FI_Ins_NO"], "FI_Ins_Amount" => number_format($value["FI_Ins_Amount"]/100  * $courseFee, 2, '.00', ''));
}, $installment);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
    $value['FI_Ins_Amount'] *= 300;
}
```

**[Codepad](http://codepad.org/TOWdQGsq)**

Comment: Thank you. At least someone having the common sense to tell him to use a 1 line foreach loop instead of constructing an awkward array_walk...

Comment: 30000/100 = 300 though not 3000.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pass additional information to the callback, you either need to use the `use` keyword, or you might be better using `array_walk()` which allows you to pas additional values to the callback functon

```
$courseFee = 30000; // 

function installmentFixed(&$value, $key, $courseFee) {
    $value["FI_Ins_Amount"] = $value["FI_Ins_Amount"] / 100  * $courseFee;
}

array_walk($instalment, "installmentFixed", $courseFee);

var_dump($instalment);
```

Note that array_walk accepts the array passed by reference, so it directly updates the original array

If you want to use array_map instead, then you're better using a closure so that you can pass the additional argument with `use`

```
$courseFee = 30000; // 

$installmentFixed = array_map(
    function ($value) use ($courseFee) {
        $value["FI_Ins_Amount"] =
            $value["FI_Ins_Amount"] / 100  * $courseFee;
        return $value;
    },
    $instalment
);

var_dump($installmentFixed);
```

Comment: where are those $key names ?

Answer (score -1):

Your installmentFixed function returns the fixed value; in this example you would get an array with two 'fixed' values in the variable $installmentFixed.

To fix the values within the array you would can potentially iterate over array element with a foreach; OR try writing (notice the pass by value)

```
function installmentFixed(&$value,$courseFee)
{
    $value["FI_Ins_Amount"] = $value["FI_Ins_Amount"]/100  * $courseFee;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$array = array (
   0=> array (
    "FI_ID"=> "577",
    "FI_Stru_Code"=> "MCTS-70-631/1",
    "FI_Ins_NO"=> "1",
    "FI_Type"=> "Percentage",
    "FI_Ins_Amount"=> "60.00"
  ),
  1=>array (
    "FI_ID"=> "578",
    "FI_Stru_Code"=> "MCTS-70-631/1",
    "FI_Ins_NO"=> "2",
    "FI_Type"=> "Percentage",
    "FI_Ins_Amount"=> "40.00"
  )
);

$courseFee = 30000; // 

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $value['FI_Ins_Amount'] = ($value['FI_Ins_Amount']/100) * $courseFee;
    $array[$key] = $value; //Without This line some php versions will not show modified value.
}

var_dump($array);

?>
```

Comment: it seems it's downvoting troll (see that all answers got downvote).

Comment: Please copy paste and browse.

Comment: my answer also was downvoted :p Since no comments left for all downvoted answers and all got -1 same time, I guess it's some angry serial downvoter :p

Comment: Forget it :) As for me - I'm sure, I'll get my votes on other answers as usual. Seriously, -2 random score because of somebody was in bad feelings is not worth my attention :p